# sending AT COMMANDS

Tags: c#, .net, c++, vba, vbscript

does anyone know where i can get the official list of all AT COMMANDS available? i would like to get my computer speaking to my cell phone. i need all AT COMMANDS and i will hook it up to either .NET or VBA or anything else.

btw i have a motorola phone

Comment: The list of AT commands depends on the phone.

Comment: @Mark Byers: True, but there is in fact an _official_ list, although that obviously doesn't have all (non-official, extension) AT commands. See Mehrdad Afshari's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the exact set of AT commands differ from device to device and you should get it from the device manufacturer, the standard variation of [Hayes AT command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) standardized by 3GPP for GSM user equipment can be found here:

[Technical Specification Group Terminals;

AT command set for User Equipment (UE)](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/27_series/27.007/27007-3d0.zip)

Comment: Note that many phones may have AT commands disabled. I know that US Cellular(or at least every phone I've tried with their branding) disables them on the phones they give out. I messed around some with my AT&T phone and the commands do not seem to be disabled(they respond appropriately) but I could never get it to make a call or anything using the official commands

Comment: @Earlz: Can't you use it to establish a "dial up" connection via Bluetooth?

Comment: @I__: Nothing. I assume you shouldn't be able to do that if AT commands are disabled, since establishing a dialup connection usually uses that.

Comment: @I__: I was talking to @Earlz re disabling AT commands for phones (i.e. if they totally disable it, dial up connection shouldn't work).

Comment: @I__: yea you should be able to use it to send text messages and other things as well. @Mehr yea I've tried doing just that, but I could never get it to work(make a dialup connection). you may want to get a prepaid phone to experiment with(AT&T) because I've heard that some providers charge for "data calls" such as dial up internet connections via AT commands..

Comment: why wouldnt they charge for it?

Answer (score 2):

Different devices support different commands. Does the manufacturer of your cell phone have a website?

Comment: its motorola, btw please let me know which newport discs u would like

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Motorola phone, then kindly follow the document given in the link below (from page no. 73) may be helpful. And every other device will be having AT commands which will differ from each other with respect to their manufacturer.

Link: [AT commands G24](https://www.coniugo.de/tl_files/dateien/downloads/at/AT_Commands_G24.pdf)